# Copy VBA code from one sheet to all other sheets in workbook

Tags: vba, copy

I have code in my workbook that i need to copy to all sheets within the workbook, so when i update the code on one sheet, i dont need to copy/paste manually to all other sheets

The code is on a mastersheet called "Contents"

Alternatively, if i can get help to apply the code to all sheets from "ThisWorkbook" (I did try this option, however i could not get it to work)

This is the code i need applied to all sheets:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ComboBox3.Value <> "" Then
    Worksheets(ComboBox3.Value).Activate
ElseIf ComboBox3.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
    Worksheets(ComboBox2.Value).Activate
Else:
    Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Activate
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim rngMenu2 As Range
Dim rngList As Range
Dim strSelected As String
Dim LastRow As Long

    ' check that a Menu1 has been selected
  If ComboBox2.ListIndex <> -1 Then
   ComboBox3.Clear
       strSelected = ComboBox2.Value

       LastRow = Worksheets("Contents").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

       Set rngList = Worksheets("Contents").Range("F1:F" & LastRow)


       For Each rngMenu2 In rngList

             If rngMenu2.Value = strSelected Then

                  ComboBox3.AddItem rngMenu2.Offset(, 1)

             End If

       Next rngMenu2

  End If
End Sub



Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim rngMenu1 As Range
Dim rngList As Range
Dim strSelected As String
Dim LastRow As Long

    ' check that a Menu1 has been selected
  If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
   ComboBox2.Clear
   ComboBox3.Clear
       strSelected = ComboBox1.Value

       LastRow = Worksheets("Contents").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

       Set rngList = Worksheets("Contents").Range("D1:D" & LastRow)


       For Each rngMenu1 In rngList

             If rngMenu1.Value = strSelected Then

                  ComboBox2.AddItem rngMenu1.Offset(, 1)

             End If

       Next rngMenu1

  End If

End Sub
```

This is the code i have to copy code to another sheet, but it only copies to 1 sheet, how can i change this to all sheets? I would also need this to delete any existing code before copying the new code to the sheets...
I have a list of sheet names in a range

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim CodeCopy As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim CodePaste As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim numLines As Integer
Dim rngList As Range
Dim LastRow As Long


       LastRow = Worksheets("Contents").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

       Set rngList = Worksheets("Contents").Range("H1:H" & LastRow)

Set CodeCopy = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule
Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet40").CodeModule

End Sub
```

Any assistance with this would be awesome (Note: im a newbie with coding! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the code in a module then call it from the events on the sheets, that way you only need to keep/update in one place.

Comment: I have added the code to a Module (Module2), How would i then have the combo boxes  on each sheet to run from the module? (I tried to search but couldnt find anything useful...)

Comment: you need to name the subs in the module something unique then inside the even you simple type the name.  so if you name the code for  `ComboBox2_Change` thus `CB2Change` then on the sheets `Private Sub ComboBox2_Change() | CB2Change | End Sub`

Comment: OK, I have named the modules: CB1Change (To populate combobox2 with items based on the item selected in combobox1), CB2Change (To populate combobox3 with items based on the selection made in combobox2), and MenuButton (To go to sheet based on selections made in comboboxes.

Comment: In the sheet code, i added the code as you suggested, however i get the error message "Compile Error, expected variable or procedure, Not Module"

Comment: How should i be referencing the module in the sheet code so the module will run as it did when i had it embedded directly into the sheet code?